# When I query with Flux in Grafana with InfluxDB, all columns except the time column are merged into a single column

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I am using Grafana 10 and influxdb 2.7.

I am using flux to get data.

```
from(bucket: "VFBckStrg")
  |> range(start: -5d)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "VMwareRawData6")
```

I should show all columns in a table in grafana.
But it shows 2 columns.
One is time column.
Second column name is combination of all column names.
But it should show all columns seperately in the table dashboard.

[Check grafana panel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz5Dc.png)

As you can see Start_Time, Client_Name and Policy_Name are shown i 1 column name.
But they shoul be seperated colums. The values you see are Start_time values.
Only Client_Name and Policy_Name are tag. Others are field.

How can i display all columns seperately.

I tried to filter column names with keep.
But not displaying columns seperately.